# How to write same value to consecutive locations in x86

Tags: c, performance, optimization, x86-64, sse

I need to achieve the following code much efficiently with an x86 machine intrinsic. Can some one suggest a solution?

```
uint64_t array[8];
array[0] = SOME_VALUE;
array[1] = SOME_VALUE;
array[2] = SOME_VALUE;
array[3] = SOME_VALUE;
array[4] = SOME_VALUE;
array[5] = SOME_VALUE;
array[6] = SOME_VALUE;
array[7] = SOME_VALUE;
```

Since same value is written to consecutive locations, if a vector/SSE intrinsic can do it efficiently, I would like to try that.

Comment: My guess is that writing to memory in blocks of the CPU's native register size would be the most efficient. I don't know if vector/SSE would help though - they are for speeding up mathematical processing rather than memory access (though there may be some memory speed-up as a side effect of block processing using register-sized blocks, but this doesn't apply to your situation).

Comment: My guess is that there will not be any gains. This fragment is memory-bus bound anyway. (will it cross a L0-cache-boundary?). It will probably setup eax and some index register(on x86) , and then flush eax to \*indexregister plus bump index. The explicit loop-unrolling will at least give the compiler some freedom, given sufficient registers. Check the ASM output.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no knowledge of the vector/SSE instructions, I've found that sometimes looking at the generated code shows that the compiler knows about the optimal machine code, and you'll find that it already generates what you hoped for. It is worth looking at the generated code to see.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memset`. glibc will take care of the optimization for you. If you think you can do better than it, you should submit a patch to the mailing list.

Also, the "instruction speed" is not likely the bottleneck here. It's probably the memory bandwidth. Unfortunately, there's no magic bullet for lowering that except for "read and write to memory less".

Comment: I actually mentioned the exact same thing to a (now deleted) answer. `memset()` only works on bytes at a time. If you want to set arrays of larger datatypes, you usually need something like `std::copy()`.

Comment: I don't think that memcpy() will perform better then the word-based assignment (it is all aligned, no need to check!)